# Compare every second line, print line after but delete duplicates

Tags: shell, sed, terminal, awk, grep

I have a file in the format of:

```
id-of-item

description of item

id-of-item

description of item

id-of-item

description of item

id-of-item

description of item

id-of-item

description of item
```

(only one line between each, just big spaces here)

I need to compare the descriptions of items and if they match, remove that description but keep the id (i need to make a table that references the ids as groups)

I have no idea how to do this, i have tried a couple of awk with NR%2 and uniq etc but obviously all have only matched one and not the other =/

Comment: can you include the actual input format instead of a the description below, including the expected output?

Comment: I don't quite understand "only one line between each". Blank lines are record separators, with descriptions possibly spanning multiple lines? Blank lines are meaningless, odd lines have IDs and even lines have single-line descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be close. The rule of awk is, 
put whatever you want to kill duplication into index of array:

```
BEGIN {title = ""}
NF == 0 { print; next;}
title == "" {
    title = $0;
    print; next;
}
{
    if (value[$0] == "" ) print;
    value[$0] = $0;
    title = ""
}
```

Feel the power of Associative Array.

Comment: that actually looks pretty much perfect, thankyou so much =]
i am very impressed by the print;next; i did not know you could do that =]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you(?):

```
# cat input.txt
id-of-item0
id-of-item0 description of item0
id-of-item1
id-of-item1 description of item1
id-of-item0
id-of-item0 description of item0
id-of-item3
id-of-item3 description of item3
id-of-item4
id-of-item4 description of item4
# sed 'N;s/\n/!!!/' input.txt | sort -u | sed 's/!!!/\n/'
id-of-item0
id-of-item0 description of item0
id-of-item1
id-of-item1 description of item1
id-of-item3
id-of-item3 description of item3
id-of-item4
id-of-item4 description of item4
```

If you want to remove the description:

```
# sed 'N;s/\n/!!!/' input.txt | sort -u | sed 's/!!!.*//'
id-of-item0
id-of-item1
id-of-item3
id-of-item4
```

Explanation:

Read `input.txt` 2 lines at a time replacing the newline `\n` with a delimiter (here it is `!!!`). Sort and remove duplicates. Replace the delimiter `!!!` by a newline `\n`. Or remove the description altogether.

EDIT:

This might work for you(?):

```
sed '/^$/d' input_file |   # remove empty lines
sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/\t/p' | # join id with description and swap tab separating
sort |                     # sort descriptions
sed ':a;N;s/^\(\([^\t]*\)\t[^\n]*\)\n\2/\1/;ta;P;D' | # build index tab separated
sed 's/\t/\n/g'            # translate tabs to newlines
```

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'm wrong! But a comment, by those wiser, might push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make two simplifying assumptions:

1. Descriptions are just one line long.
2. You can identify a character that doesn't appear in descriptions or IDs. I'll use a tab for this character.

Neither assumption is very strong, so it shouldn't be hard to adapt the following if needed.

With those assumptions, I'll produce sample data with `printf "1\n\nitem 1\n\n2\n\nitem 2\n\n3\n\nitem 2\n\n4\n\nitem 1\n"`. It looks like this:

```
1

item 1

2

item 2

3

item 2

4

item 1
```

To process this data, I'll:

1. Get rid of the blank lines
2. Join successive lines, separating the ID and description by a tab
3. Sort the new lines by the description field
4. Format the sorted lines into a table

Here's a pipeline that does it:

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' |        
  awk 'NR%2 { printf("%s\t", $0) } !(NR%2)' | 
    sort -k2 | 
      awk -F"\t" 'desc != $2 { printf("-----\n%s\n", $2); desc = $2} { print $1 }'
```

Pipe the sample data through it, and you get

```
-----
item 1
1
4
-----
item 2
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
awk 'NF' file | sed '{N;s/\n/:/g}' | 
awk -F":" -v OFS="\n\n" -v ORS="\n\n"  '{b[$2]++} {if (b[$2]>1) print $1; else print $1,$2}'
```

**Your File:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
id-of-item31

description of item4 <--- Duplicate description

id-of-item22

description of item4 <--- Duplicate description

id-of-item34

description of item1 <--- Duplicate description

id-of-item21

description of item3

id-of-item11

description of item1 <--- Duplicate description
```

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NF' file | sed '{N;s/\n/:/g}' | 
awk -F":" -v OFS="\n\n" -v ORS="\n\n"  '{b[$2]++} {if (b[$2]>1) print $1; else print $1,$2}'

id-of-item31

description of item4

id-of-item22

id-of-item34

description of item1

id-of-item21

description of item3

id-of-item11
```

Comment: Oh my bad! I had converted the main file in to a temp file for my tests. I will update the answer above.